# Parents vs in-laws-- using bad words

Tags: hadith

Once I saw in yearly Calendar & also my father tells me that " if i say bad words or scold (not in front) about my parent in-laws, it is as if I am scolding my parents". Since then I have stopped, but I would like to know if this is correct or if there is any "Hadith" on this matter. If so, where can i get them?

In general, I know we should not be using bad words about anybody, but I want to make sure of the fact that if there is "Hadith on scolding parent in-laws befalls on own parents. I am not sure if I have explained my self well enough. thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I would not want the answer to be e-mailed to me. If you could post the answer, i will appreciate . thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah,

I have not come across a hadith that talks about slandering and insulting in-laws; however, the closest [hadith](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/4) (in meaning) that I remember is:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said. "It is one of the greatest sins that a man
>   should curse his parents." It was asked (by the people), "O Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ)! How does a man curse his parents?" The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said, "'**The man abuses the father of another man and the latter abuses
>   the father of the former and abuses his mother.**"

On a side note, you wrote the following:

> " if i say bad words or scold (**not in front**) about my parent
>   in-laws..."

**This is even worse than just insulting/scolding your in-laws**. You are talking badly about them behind their back, and of course you know that backbiting is considered by almost all of the Scholars as **a major sin**.

Allah knows best!